# Take the list of attached devices

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

when I type `adb devices` in the shell 
I get something like this

```
List of devices attached 
HT06RPQ002T1    device
HT06RPQ002T1    device
```

I want some shell script that will print just the ids of the phones
for example in this case to print

```
HT06RPQ002T1
HT06RPQ002T1
```

if more devices are attached to print more ids...

Thanks

EDIT

I tried to put everything in a variable like this
asd=`adb devices`
but I do not have idea how to parse if I have one device attached or I have 10 devices...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
adb devices | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}'
```

Comment: this prints 
"of
device" , I need the actual id and also if 2 phones are connected I need both ids

Comment: it skips the first line "List of devices attached"

Comment: @Lukap: `NR` is the current record number. It's updated automatically as each line (record) is read.

Answer (score 1):

```
flag=false

while read -r device type
do
    if ! $flag
    then
        flag=true
        continue
    fi
    echo "$device"
done < <(adb devices)
```

Comment: sorry but this snippet doesn't print any output , is this the whole snippet ?